# repo method naming convention

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, data-access-layer

I'm creating a reference model for the Repository layer in a new app.  I'm starting with UserRepository. I like the idea of following a CRUD (Create-Read-Update-Delete) naming convention at the repo level. This feels natural for the GetById method:

`public User Read(int userId)`

It seems to feel less natural for the Search method:

`public List<User> Read(UserQuery query)`

Do you ever try to follow a CRUD naming convention for your repositories?  Would you define a Search method signature in the way I defined my second method signature above or would you follow a different naming convention?

Comment: Worth reading this: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/10/08/favor-query-objects-over-repositories/

Answer (score 3):

I like to give my repositories [collection semantics](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). Something along the lines of `Add()`, `Remove()` and a series of `Get()`'s.

Not necessarily `Update()`, since it doesn't make a lot of sense to tell a collection to update an element, you usually get the object from the collection then modify it directly instead.

This comes from a Domain Driven Design perspective where the original definition of a Repository is an illusion of an in-memory collection. The repository interface is defined in the Domain layer, so it is not supposed to have any reference to persistence-related things.

To put it simply, a Repository is just a bag of things that you can look into, add to and remove from.

`Search()` fits perfectly in this vision. You can also use the [Specification pattern](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/02/08/specification-pattern-c-implementation/) to make search criteria more fluent and reusable.

Comment: all things being equal this makes sense to me. If I want to update an item in the bag of things this implies a get(), remove() then add()?

Comment: Oftentimes it's not just one item modified in a business transaction but multiple, and you want the set of changes to be atomic. Knowing when to commit changes is sometimes not at the same level of the call stack as pulling an existing item out of a Repository. Therefore I put the `Save()` method in some kind of encompassing Unit of Work. The code that calls the repo just modifies the item, it is "put back in the bag" elsewhere.